# WordPress: Filter Priority not working

Tags: wordpress, filter, hook

I am trying to add attachment gallery after the_content() but it is not moving to below the_content() but top of the_content()

I have set priority to 9999 and still not working. Any idea or suggestion please?

```
add_filter('the_content', 'admin_gallery_after_content', 9999);
function admin_gallery_after_content($content)
{
    $admin_gallery = new q2a_rm_front;
    $content .= $admin_gallery->rm_admin_gallery();
    return $content;    
}
```

Comment: What does the class q2a returns?

Comment: It returns post type in this format `'post','music'`

Comment: I am sorry ignore above comment.. just confused with different question.. that class returns post attachments

Comment: Look at the source of the page. Is it at the bottom or the top in the _source_, or is CSS causing to appear at the top? Or is broken markup causing an issue?

Comment: no it is not executing the code at all for that part